# Xpath: Two joined collections?

Tags: xpath

I don't even know how to describe this :)

I have bunch of `div`s, with similar IDs that have random part added to each (the random part is different for each session). and *deeply* nested in one of them a bunch of radio input boxes, without anything I can tie to (also the whole tree under the `div` doesn't have unique attributes I can tie to).

I need the first radio button. I get the needed div with `(//div[contains(@id,'div-question')])[2]`, and I thought I could follow it up with similar construct, but I can't figure out how. I Also tired following:

```
(//div[contains(@id,'div-question')])[2]//input[@type='radio' and position() = 1]
```

but it return me all radio buttons, not only the first one (I'm using FirePath from FireBug -- could it be it's bug?)

So, how do I join two `//...` searches?

Comment: Can you post an example HTML on some website such as jsfiddle?

Comment: @IlyaKogan - https://jsfiddle.net/cvy5voae/ , thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//x[position()=1]` returns every descendant x that is the first child of its parent. To select the first descendant x, you need `(//x)[position()=1]`. With a complex path it becomes easier to use the descendant axis explicitly rather than the `//` shorthand:

```
    descendant::div[contains(@id,'div-question')][2]
    /descendant::input[@type='radio'][1]
```